# Canvas 2d Only Displays Last Drawing in Series of Elements

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a simple script that adds a new canvas to a div container for each clock that needs to be drawn based on the number of minutes given. The script will draw the canvas elements without fail and will draw the clock face in the last canvas element however it will not draw a clock face on any preceding canvas elements. Upon review of the console, the output is identical for the canvas elements both with and without the clock face. Not sure what is happening with this. Below is a JSFiddle with my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/1oxfgwkb/

The HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="clockHolder"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript

```
var time = 115;
var holder = document.getElementById("clockHolder");
var clockNum = Math.ceil((time / 60));
for(var q = 1; q <= clockNum; q++) {
    var clockFace = 'sample-'+q;
    holder.innerHTML += '<canvas id="'+clockFace+'" width="35" height="35"></canvas>';
    drawClock(clockFace);
}

function drawClock(clockFace) {
    var c = document.getElementById(clockFace);
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var radius = (c.height / 2) * 0.9;
    var midpoint = c.height / 2;
    for(var i=1; i<=12; i++) {
        var angle = (i*30) * Math.PI / 180;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(100,100,100,0.75)';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.translate(midpoint, midpoint);
        ctx.rotate(angle);
        ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.9);
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(0,4);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#555';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(midpoint, midpoint, radius*0.9, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's drawing them both but setting the innerHTML of the parent is overwriting all but the last. Setting the innerHTML doesn't preserve existing elements, it makes new ones with identical attributes--but without whatever content you updated in the meantime.

Instead try:

```
for(var q = 1; q <= clockNum; q++) {
    holder.innerHTML += '<canvas id="sample-'+q+'" width="35" height="35"></canvas>';
}

for(var q = 1; q <= clockNum; q++) {
    drawClock('sample-'+q);
}
```

You could also use `document.createElement` and then `holder.append`.